# Postgres convert json with duplicate IDs

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

With this select:

```
json_agg(json_build_object("id", price::money))
```

I get the resulting value:

```
[
  {"6" : "$475.00"}, 
  {"6" : "$1,900.00"},
  {"3" : "$3,110.00"},
  {"3" : "$3,110.00"}
]
```

I would like the data in this format instead:

```
{
  "6": ["$475.00","$1,900.00"],
  "3": ["$3,110.00","$3,110.00"]
}
```

When queried on the server or used with jsonb, the IDs are duplicate and only one of the key value pairs make it through.

Comment: Maybe [array_agg(price::money)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) fixes it but a bit hard to tell without example data..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should aggregate prices in groups by ids and use the aggregate function `json_object_agg()`. You have to use a derived table (subquery in the from clause) because aggregates cannot be nested:

```
select json_object_agg(id, prices)
from (
    select id, json_agg(price::money) as prices
    from my_table
    group by id
    ) s
```

[Working example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/OEEAE50784)

Comment: Everything is wrapped in an array:[{"6" : ["$475.00", "$1,900.00"]}, {"3" : ["$3,110.00", "$3,110.00"]}], i'd like it to just be an object: {"6" : ["$475.00", "$1,900.00"], "3" : ["$3,110.00", "$3,110.00"]}

Comment: I realized I had formatted my question wrong, I've edited it to reflect that comment. Sorry!